# How to hide elements not specified in grid-template-areas?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to understand `grid-template-areas`.

I've this HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
.wrapper {
    grid-template-areas: "areaA areaB areaC areaD" 
}

.A { grid-area: areaA; }
.B { grid-area: areaB; }
.C { grid-area: areaC; }
.D { grid-area: areaD; }
```

I get the (expected) following result

```
A B C D
```

now if I add a media query, and wanted to hide column B, C and D

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .wrapper {
        grid-template-areas: "areaA";
    }

    .B {
        display: none;
    }

    .C {
        display: none;
    }

    .D {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

this also works :

```
A
```

now, I then removed the `display:none` entries, hoping that because there was no mention of the elements in `grid-template-areas` that they would not show. I was wrong ;)

Is it possible to specify just using css-grid that elements not specified are hidden by default ? I can't seem to find anything that mentions this

Comment: No...if an element is not assigned a *explicit* grid-area it appears **after** the last area as determined by the *implicit* grid

Comment: There is no such way, unfortunately. You still need to use 'display: none;' or 'visibility: hidden' to hide the elements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [**`grid-template-areas`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) property cannot hide grid items. It is designed to create grid areas.

But your media query can still be very simple.

This is all you need:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {

   section:not(.a) { display: none; }

}
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7pn2sb58/)

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "areaA areaB areaC areaD";
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  section:not(.a) { display: none; }
}

.a { grid-area: areaA; }
.b { grid-area: areaB; }
.c { grid-area: areaC; }
.d { grid-area: areaD; }

/* non-essential demo styles */

section {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section class="d">D</section>
  <section class="b">B</section>
  <section class="c">C</section>
  <section class="a">A</section>
</article>
```

Comment: In order to not display multiple selectors, you can chain them, e.g. section:not(.a):not(.d) { display: none; }

Comment: Can you target a particular grid area this way? `section:not([grid-area=whatever])` seems right but isn't working for me

Comment: @JonathanTuzman `section:not([grid-area=whatever])` is to select a `<section>` that is `:not` a `<... grid-area="whatever">`. That selector uses an [Attribute selectors (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), but `grid-area` is a [CSS property (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area), not an HTML attribute.