# How to hide content in CSS Grid?

Tags: css, html, layout, media-queries, css-grid

I'm working on a site top bar with 3 elements to place:

- social icons
- search form
- secondary nav

I have 3 media queries where I want to display:

- small screens show just the nav
- medium screens show nav + social
- large screens show all 3

Top bar will be a nested grid inside the site's main grid - I know in some cases, this matters.

Would greatly appreciate understanding why this code isn't working and what would work. Many thanks!

Pen: https://codepen.io/ljburton/pen/eKvaax

```css
/* define grid areas */
#site-top-bar .nav {grid-area: top-nav;}
#site-top-bar .social {grid-area: top-social;}
#site-top-bar .search {grid-area: top-search;}

/*grid for phone*/
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  #site-top-bar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1;
    grid-template-areas: "top-nav";   
  } 
}

/*grid for tablet-portrait-up*/
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #site-top-bar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2;
    grid-template-areas: "top-social top-nav";   
  } 
}  

/*grid for tablet-landscape-up*/
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  #site-top-bar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3;
    grid-template-areas: "top-social top-search top-nav";   
  }  
}
```

```html
<div id="site-top-bar">
  <ul class="nav nav-hor">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="social">
    <div>T</div>
    <div>F</div>
    <div>P</div>
    <div>I</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found answer here:
[hide elements not specified in grid-template-areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660366/hide-elements-not-specified-in-grid-template-areas)

In CSS Grid, if content isn't explicitly placed, it will be implicitly placed.

Meaning grids will display all items and you'll need a separate rule to hide unwanted content.

In the end, this made the @media rules much simpler.

Updating Pen to show difference.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* -------------------- 
Styles: Global
-------------------- */
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.62;
}

/* -------------------- 
Grid - Social Icons
-------------------- */
/* define grid for social icons */
div.social {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 48px);
  grid-auto-rows: 64px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
}
/* -------------------- 
Grid - Social Icons
-------------------- */
/* define grid for social icons */
div.social {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 48px);
  grid-auto-rows: 64px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

/* align each icon within it's div */
div.social div {
  background: #ffffff;
} 

#site-top-bar{margin: 40px; background: #e1e1e1;}
h1{font-size: 2em;}
h2{font-size: 1.6em;}
h3{font-size: 1.3em;}

ul.nav {margin:0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
ul.nav li {display: inline;}

/* -------------------- 
grid-template-area ORIGINAL
-------------------- */
/* define grid areas */
#site-top-bar .nav {grid-area: top-nav;}
#site-top-bar .social {grid-area: top-social;}
#site-top-bar .search {grid-area: top-search;}


#site-top-bar{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'top-social top-search top-nav';
}

/*grid for tablet-portrait*/
@media all and (max-width: 992px) {
  #site-top-bar .search {display:none;}
}

/*grid for phone*/
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  #site-top-bar .social { display:none; }
  #site-top-bar .search {display:none;}
}
```

```html
<div id="site-top-bar">
  <ul class="nav nav-hor">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="social">
    <div>T</div>
    <div>F</div>
    <div>P</div>
    <div>I</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will work for you.